# Runtime error NoClassDefFoundError with apache common codec jar

Tags: java, jar, runtime-error

I have a java class (SecureHash) that uses the functionalities of apache common codec. I am compiling the code with

```
javac -classpath sample/module/commons-codec-1.8.jar  sample/SampleAcn.java sample/module/SampleLoginModule.java sample/module/SecureHash.java
```

I do not get any error with compilation, but I get a runtime errors, when the a SecureHash is initialized:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
    at sample.module.SampleLoginModule.login(SampleLoginModule.java:242)
    .....


 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
         .....
```

I cannot get the reason for this error, as I'm including the jar to the common codec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the setting the CLASSPATH correctly when you run your classes? You also need to point for the location of sample/module/commons-codec-1.8.jar.

Comment: I'm sure I'm pointing at the right path for the codec jar. Otherwise I think it wouldn't have compiled at all I suppose

Comment: Well, compilation and execution are independent processes. Sorry if by saying that I am mistakenly assuming you are a newbie. When you run your class you need to pass the whole classpath again, plus the location of the classes you just built:  
  

    java -classpath sample/module/commons-codec-1.8.jar:dir_where_you_can_find_your_classes your.main.Class

Comment: You were completely right. I misunderstood that you meant to add the classpath during the run and I feel kinda stupid for that, but thanks a lot!

Comment: Absolutely no need to feel that way. We are all learning here.

Just glad I could offer you a little shortcut! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the dependencies here you might also need `commons-logging`, but you've probably already got that.